# How to avoid based on Below code inserted the Record when i insert and update Only one time will populate on the ChildObject

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger TshirstCase on Account (after insert,after update) {
for(Account acc:Trigger.new){
Case c = new Case();
c.Subject ='Hey TshirtCase';
c.Origin ='Phone';
c.Status ='New';
c.Priority ='Medium';
c.AccountId =acc.id;
insert c;
}
}
```

Comment: So your will be under one account only one case created right?

Comment: Simple. Remove after update

Comment: @renu, if you reframe the question properly, it could be more meaningful and can also be helpful for other members

Answer (score 1):

Don't do DML operations inside for loop. You are inserting case record inside for loop. So you will get Limit Exceptions. Put all your cases in a list and then at the end do the insert with Database.insert method.

Read - [Trigger and Bulk Request Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_bestpract.htm)

If I understand correctly, you don't want more than one cases under account, correct?
You can create a map where Account Id will be the key and List of Cases associated with that account will be the value. Iterate through the map and then create cases only when for a particular account, the size of the case list if 0. Here is the code snippet -

```
trigger TshirstCase on Account (after insert,after update) { 
    List<id> accountIds = new List<Id>();
    List<Case> allCasesToBeInserted = new List<Case>();

    for(Account acc:Trigger.new){ 
        accountIds.add(acc.Id);
    } 

    List<Case> allCases = [Select Id, AccountId from Case where AccountId in: accountIds];
    Map<Id, Integer> accountNumberOfCaseMap = new Map<Id, Integer>();
    for(Case c : allCases){
        Integer count;
        if(accountNumberOfCaseMap.get(c.AccountId) == null){
            count=0;
        }else{
            count=accountNumberOfCaseMap.get(c.AccountId).value();
            count = count+1;
        }
        accountNumberOfCaseMap.put(c.AccountId,count);
    }

    for(Account acc:Trigger.new){
        if(accountNumberOfCaseMap.get(acc.Id).value() == 0){
            Case c = new Case(  Subject ='Hey TshirtCase',
                                Origin ='Phone',
                                Status ='New',
                                Priority ='Medium',
                                AccountId =acc.id); 
            allCasesToBeInserted.add(c);
        }
    }

    if(allCasesToBeInserted.size() > 0){
        Database.insert(allCasesToBeInserted);
    }
}
```

Comment: code needs to be refactored as still DML in loop

Comment: Ohh sorry!! Need to remove the insert statement from the for loop. Problem of copy paste from the original question.

Comment: Corrected now. Thanks Santanu for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code snippet : -

```
trigger TshirstCase on Account (after insert,after update) { 
    List<id> accountIds = new List<Id>();
    List<Case> lst_casesinserted = new List<Case>();
     Map<Id, Id> accountcaseMap = new Map<Id, Integer>();

    if(Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert ||  Trigger.isUpdate){ 
        for(Account acc:Trigger.new){ 
            accountIds.add(acc.Id);//list of accounts for which trigger will be fired
        }   
    }

    List<Case> allCases = [Select Id, AccountId from Case where AccountId in: accountIds];// query on the contacts
    if(!allCases.isEmpty() && allCases.size()>0){
        for(Case c : allCases){
            accountcaseMap.put(c,AccountId,c.Id);//map of accounts and case
        }
    }
    for(Account acc:Trigger.new){
        if(!accountcaseMap.containsKey(acc.Id)){//check whether the account is present  
            Case c = new Case(  Subject ='Hey TshirtCase',
                                Origin ='Phone',
                                Status ='New',
                                Priority ='Medium',
                                AccountId =acc.id); 
            lst_casesinserted.add(c);
        }
    }

    if(lst_casesinserted.size() > 0){
        Database.insert(lst_casesinserted);//insert the case
    }
}
```

trigger will be working fine.

Comment: put little bit writing on what she is doing wrong and what can be best way to achieve. In that case, it will more helpful for other members